# skip pipeline for a branch in workflow keyword

Tags: gitlab, cicd

While developing  gitlab ci-cd pipeline i want to run pipeline manually for a particular branch for example branch name is "develop-tool". what i want is anything done on this branch should not trigger pipeline automatically. it should be manually. what i have tried is:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - when: manual    # Error: workflow:rules:rule when unknown value: manual
```

then i tried to do this:

```
- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" &&  $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME !~ /^.*-$develop-tool/'
    - when: always
```

its taking job to some infinite loop and it keeps running until and unless you cancel it and run the job again. does anyone have any other way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

Have the configuration skip pipelines when the source is not the web for that branch. So the only way it can be triggered on that branch is through the web UI.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop-tool" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "web"'
    when: never
  - when: always
```

Comment: if i am adding this it is not running pipeline at all .